# How to return string from a function to another function?

Tags: javascript

I've made a login form that will check that username and password are valid or not.

Everything is good, until I press Login.

After press login button it said that username and password is wrong although it is not.

How could I fix this? I think it is about `return` in `userCheck()` and `pwdCheck()` functions.

Here is my form

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
 <input type="text" id="user" name="user" onfocus="userFocus()" onblur="userBlur()">
<span id="userWarn" class="warnSpan">Username is required.</span>
 <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" onfocus="pwdFocus()" onblur="pwdBlur()">
<span id="pwdWarn" class="warnSpan">Username is required.</span>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var pwdElem = document.getElementById("pwd");
var pwdVal = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var pwdWarn = document.getElementById("pwdWarn");
var pwdLen = pwdVal.length;
var pwdCheck = pwdCheck();
var userElem = document.getElementById("user");
var userVal = document.getElementById("user").value;
var userWarn = document.getElementById("userWarn");
var userLen = userVal.length;
var userCheck = userCheck();

function userFocus()
{
 userElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ccffff"; 
 userElem.style.border = "1px inset #00ffff";
 userElem.style.color = "#00ffff";
}

function userBlur()
{
 var userLenx = document.getElementById("user").value.length;

 if (userLenx != 0)
 {
  userOk();
 }
 else
 {
  userError();
 }
}

function pwdFocus() 
{
 pwdElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ccffff"; 
 pwdElem.style.border = "1px inset #00ffff";
 pwdElem.style.color = "#00ffff";
}

function pwdBlur()
{
 var pwdLenx = document.getElementById("pwd").value.length;

 if (pwdLenx >= 8)
 {
  pwdOk();
 }
 else
 {
  pwdError();
 }
}

function userCheck()
{
 var userLenx = document.getElementById("user").value.length;

 if (userLenx != 0)
 {
  return "ok";
 }
 else
 {
  return "error";
 }
}

function pwdCheck() 
{
 var pwdLenx = document.getElementById("pwd").value.length;

 if (pwdLen >= 8)
 {
  return "ok";
 }
 else
 {
  return "error";
 }
}

function userError()
{
 userElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffcccc"; 
 userElem.style.border = "1px inset #ff0000";
 userElem.style.color = "#ff0000";
 userWarn.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function pwdError() 
{
 pwdElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffcccc"; 
 pwdElem.style.border = "1px inset #ff0000";
 pwdElem.style.color = "#ff0000";
 pwdWarn.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function userOk()
{
 userElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ddffdd"; 
 userElem.style.border = "1px outset #00bb00";
 userElem.style.color = "#00bb00";
 userWarn.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function pwdOk()
{
 pwdElem.style.backgroundColor = "#ddffdd"; 
 pwdElem.style.border = "1px outset #00bb00";
 pwdElem.style.color = "#00bb00";
 pwdWarn.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function errorForm()
{
 if (userCheck=="error"&&pwdCheck=="error")
 {
  userError();
  pwdError();
 }
 else if (userCheck=="error"&&pwdCheck=="ok")
 {
  userError();
 }
 else if (userCheck=="ok"&&pwdCheck=="error")
 {
  pwdError();
 }
 else
 {
  alert("Sorry, an error occured.\n\nPlease refresh page and try again.");
 }
}

function loginSubmit()
{
 if (userCheck=="ok"&&pwdCheck=="ok")
 {
  userOk();
  pwdOk();
  loginForm.submit();
 }
 else
 {
  errorForm();
 }
}
```

Here is the [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qicopapana/1/watch?output)

Please help, I am new to coding!

Comment: Please share the specific code in the question, it's not funny to go to other site just to read a question....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Additionally, it's not a great idea to do the username/password checks in Javascript - it's client-side, so [anyone could view the source code to see what the username/passwords](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/So-You-Hacked-Our-Site!) are, or even change them.

Comment: I have edit the post with some codes. I don't care if someone is going to edit the code, it doesn't make any terrible damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with you code seems to be in the function loginSubmit(). It should read as follows:

```
function loginSubmit()
{
 if (userCheck()=="ok"&&pwdCheck()=="ok") // <--change here
 {
  userOk();
  pwdOk();
  loginForm.submit();
 }
 else
 {
  errorForm();
 }
}
```

The two variables you were referring to (`userCheck` and `pwdCheck`) are initialised as soon as the page loads. This means they will represent the state of the login and password fields when the page loads. Since these fields are empty when the page loads, the `loginSubmit()` function will always show the error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I have forgot, check functions execute only when window load! Here is the final result on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mokisoxefo/2/watch?output) Although I didn't do the same way with you, but your explanation help me!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string from the function, but you aren't using it for anything...

Short example

```
function getString() {
    return "A string";
}

// I don't even store the string...
getString();
```

So to fix it, use the string that is returned

```
// Store it
var example = getString();

// Use it
alert(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do the validation which you are trying

```
function validate()
{
    if(trim(document.frmLogin.sUserName.value)=="")
    {
      alert("Username is required.");
      document.frmLogin.sUserName.focus();
      return false;
    }
    else if(trim(document.frmLogin.sPwd.value)=="")
    {
      alert("Please Enter a Password");
      document.frmLogin.sPwd.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a problem with the way you are trying to call userCheck, pwdCheck, etc.

You are missing the parentheses, which means you are comparing the function itself (i.e. not the result of calling the function) with a string.

your comparisons should look something like this once you've added the parentheses

```
    if (userCheck()=="error"&&pwdCheck()=="error")
```